# satellizer is asking for a token?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, token, satellizer

I am using satellizer to make a signup form. But whenever i try to signup, it gives me this error

> Error: Expecting a token named "token" but instead got:
>   {"email":"qwe@adfs.com","id":11}
>       at Object.angular.module.constant.provider.factory.shared.setToken (satellizer.js:312)
>       at satellizer.js:420
>       at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular.js:11682)
>       at angular.js:11768
>       at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:12811)
>       at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:12623)
>       at Scope.ng.config.$provide.decorator.$delegate.**proto**.$digest (:844:31)
>       at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:12915)
>       at Scope.ng.config.$provide.decorator.$delegate.**proto**.$apply (:855:30)
>       at done (angular.js:8450)

what is going wrong?

Comment: in your server side what do you use as platform and how do you write your  token in the response?

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong. Satellizer has http intereptors configured for those kind of stuff.

It expects when HTTP status is 200 (OK) from you to send him a JSON field "token" for example:

{token:'some token'}.

[image]

You can see here it is checking if you as a user have authentication already or if you set your httpInterceptors to true or false.

Send it some custom value for the beginning to figure out how it is working, play a bit with config. Everything is explained on a Github

Cheers.